# Swift ObjectMapper: Map array of objects that inherit from base object

Tags: swift, objectmapper

I have a base parent object like this:

```
class A: Mappable {
    var x: String!
    ...
}
```

And two children of it:

```
class Child1: A {
    var y: Int!
    ...
}

class Child2: A {
    var z: String?
}
```

All this is good and dandy, but what happens when I have an object that represents an array of objects that inherit from A such as:

```
class Wrapper: Mappable {
    var objcs: [A]? // A will always be either Child1 or Child2, never A directly
}
```

How do I manage this situation? (little detail, I need to be able to use Wrapper from Obj-c as well, didn't add the annotations and NSObject inheritance to avoid being verbose)

Comment: What's the actual problem?

Comment: the problem is that the library will not recognise the objects in Wrapper as possibly Child1 or ChildB types, and will instead cast them all as A.

Comment: Why is that a problem? This is standard OO programming. Look up inheritance and overriding

Comment: I dont think you understood my question JeremyP. My problem wasn't a lack of knowledge on OO programming, but a lack of knowledge on where to hook to properly cast my objects in ObjectMapper. I added the answer for anyone who might be interested.

Comment: If you have to look inside an object to find out what it is, that's a code smell.  Your design probably needs to be looked at again.

Comment: I agree, but the models are mapped after an API over which I have no control

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this issue, so I'm leaving this for posterity in case anyone runs across this issue:

I had to implement a custom TransformType (a protocol of the ObjectMapper library) that takes the list of `[Any]` and converts them independently to either Child1 or Child2 depending on the internal structure of Any